# Karate file upload issue when having mandatory metadata

Tags: file, upload, metadata, karate

Facing file upload issue with multiple metadata below is request and response

multipart field metadata = {"key":"File_extension", "value":"jpg"}

response: details : "Doctyp,filename,tag mandatory

when add another metadata

multipart field metadata = {"key":"File_extension", "value":"jpg"}

multipart field metadata = {"key":"File_name", "value":"Test"}

response: "required list parameter 'metadata' is not present

Could you please help me on this

Comment: multipart related questions are the hardest to answer so please figure this out yourself. all the information you need can be found here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1645#issuecomment-862502881

Comment: I don't understand at all. just follow this process (if you can): https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: please refer https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1988