# Karate API: File upload Possible in lower version (0.9.5) but unable proces the same in another version(1.3.0.RC1)

Tags: api, karate

Excecuted the below statement in 0.9.5 version and get the proper response.

URL : ""

- header Content-Tyep= "multipart/formdata"
- multipart field metadata = {"key":"FILE_NAME",
  "vale":"test" }
- multipart field metadata = {"key":"FILE_EXTENSION",

"vale":"jpg" }
........

- method post
- status 200
  get proper response

but in 1.3.0.RC1 getting below error
required list parameter 'metadata ' is not present

please suggest some ideas

is there any alternative way for above 0.9.5 versions

Comment: I have nothing to add to the comments I made to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71911893/143475

Comment: my previous one is not working in older version as well but now mine working untill version 0.9.5 but above this I can't proceed

Comment: hopefully someone else here can help you